# More than one DbContext was found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am implementing a code first database using AspCore 2. I have a "DataContext.cs" that goes like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddelName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateAdded { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) {}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
             base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

          //AspNetUsers -> User
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("User");
        //AspNetRoles -> Role
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
            .ToTable("Role");
        //AspNetUserRoles -> UserRole
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
            .ToTable("UserRole");
        //AspNetUserClaims -> UserClaim
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
            .ToTable("UserClaim");
        //AspNetUserLogins -> UserLogin
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
            .ToTable("UserLogin");
    }
}
```

and this in my "startup.cs"

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

When I try running the dotnet migration, `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` I get the following error:

> "More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands."

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It looks like there are several classes that have been inherited from DbContext class (may have come from some NuGet package). So add migration with

```
Add-Migration MyMigration -context DataContextName
```

Comment: I even tried this => dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --ConfigurationTypeName [DatingApp.API].Migrations.DataContext.Configuration but I get the error of Unrecognized option "-ConfiguaritonTypeName"

Comment: Use `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context DataContext`

Comment: @Ibanez1408 it should be `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -ConfigurationTypeName DatingApp.API.Migrations.DataContext.Configuration`. One '-' less. I also removed the braces, never saw that syntax .. might work though.

Comment: The DatingApp.API is one word. I enclosed it in brackets

Comment: I get this error => ``Unrecognized option '-ConfigurationTypeName'

Comment: There’s no `ConfigurationTypeName` option, I really don’t know where you took that from… Run `dotnet ef migrations add --help` for usage information.

Answer (score 13):

please follow [this syntax](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/commands/pmc-commands)

```
Add-Migration [-Name] <String> [-OutputDir <String>] [-Context <String>] [-Project <String>] [-StartupProject <String>] [-Environment <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

in your case,

```
add-migration MyMigration -Context DataContext
```

Comment: This syntax worked for me in the Package Manager Console, I had to also specify the project because I believe PMC was targeting the wrong one. `add-migration MyMigration -context MyDbContext -project MyDatabaseProject`

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

```
dotnet ef migrations add <your_migration_name> -c <your_context_class_name>
```

**[--context  | -c]**

> The DbContext class to use. Class name only or fully qualified with
> namespaces. If this option is omitted, EF Core will find the context
> class. If there are multiple context classes, this option is required.

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#common-options

Answer (score 6):

```
update-database -Context YourContext
```

Comment: You might want to extend your answer and explain how this command solves the problem

Answer (score 3):

When We have more than one DbContext class which is inherited from DbContext ,for evrey one Like PrsWebAppContext class

> public class PrsWebAppContext : DbContext

we can write:

**NameSpace**:PrsWebApp.Data

**ClassName**:PrsWebAppContext

```
PM> add-migration initial -context PrsWebApp.Data.PrsWebAppContext
```

Build started...
Build succeeded.

For More information please refer to :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMBAeHaqrVs

Answer (score 2):

**Wrong code:**

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

**Right code**

```
services.AddDbContext<YourContextClassName>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Also, `YourContextClassName` should inherit `DbContext` but you named it `DbContext`.

This question is pretty old but my answer is relevant as I encountered the same while moving a project  from `MySQL` to `SQLServer`.

Comment: this was my issue

Answer (score 2):

for Mac os in visual studio i did like this. its working

```
dotnet ef database update -c ApplicationDbContext
```

Comment: Was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62923312/861716).

Comment: @GertArnold that not working in Mac os

Answer (score 1):

First of all solve this problem by adding migration. So add migration with:

`Add-Migration MyMigration -context DataContext`

if you are not able to solve this problem from now or Still facing a problem when add a new controller then add following code portion in your DB context:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDBContextConnection");

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of you already have migrations created but still it gives the error on database update command then this command can be helpful to solve it

> dotnet ef database update -p Infrastructure -s API --context
> StoreContext

Answer (score 0):

Specify DbContext after migration name, message guided you to use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.

for cmd:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context DataContext
```

for PowerShell:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -context DataContext
```