# .NET 6 Extend IdentityDbContext without having multiple contexts when using migrations

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity

I am eventually trying to create a library to help me implement Identity into a .NET 6 webapi.  I am trying to separate all my code for auth into it's own files so I can eventually replace with my custom library.  I want to shied my app from the ApiUser, if I can. I have an issue now where I am getting the error "More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use...."

I am not sure how to extend the IdentityDbContext so that I can inject some tables/data of my own without needing to specify which context to use.  Technically, my app only uses the one context "ApiDbContext".

ApiAuthIdentityContext.cs  -  this hides ApiUser and injects seed data

```
public class ApiAuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApiUser>
    {
        public ApiAuthDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }
    }


    public class ApiDbContext : ApiAuthDbContext
    {
        public ApiDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApiDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            //seed data for auth
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new SeedDataRoles());


        }
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration["DbConnection"])
            );
```

Is there another way to do this where the app only sees the ApiDbContext?

Comment: I know I can just use --context when migrating, but I don't see why I should have to.

Comment: I'm not sure why I can extend DbContext, but not this new class I just created?

Comment: There's a previous post that addresses this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311053/more-than-one-dbcontext-was-found.

As long as there are multiple classes inheriting from DbContext in the same assembly you'll be prompted with this message. Once you extract `ApiAuthDbContext` into its own library you'll probably stop seeing this message.